# Can establish https connection without certificat on client device?

Tags: ios, web-services, ssl, https

I want to do Client/Server communication with HTTP/HTTPS encapsulation.

The HTTPS mode is used just for encryption data, i don't need authentification.

For HTTPS connection, I created and installed certificat on server side. Is it possible to connect to server even if client has no certificat? (I think Yes but....)

PS: I developed client on Windows, Android and iOS

Thanks

Comment: Did you even try? This is the most common case.

Comment: Yes i tried with PC devices. This device didn't have the certificat. ANd the communication has runned and data were encrypted. But is it the same with iOS or Android?

Comment: I think, if it's just for encryption without authentification, the client doesn't need the certificat Is it correct?

Comment: If you don't want to authenticate the client you don't need to. But authentication of the server is still required (with a server side certificate) or otherwise you would be open to man-in-the-middle attacks. It is actually the common case if you use https inside the browser that the server certificate gets verified but no client certificates are involved.

Comment: Thanks Steffen, I've another system for the authentification. So my HTTPS  is just for the encryption. In conclusion, don't need certificat ni client side to have data encryption between client and server, just a certificat in server side. And that for all type of devices (iOS Android Windows)!!!

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Does anyone know why my client responds to my server Encrypted alert (21) ->Decryption failed?

Comment: Probably some unknown error in some unknown code. Maybe you connect with TLS to a server port without TLS.  If you want help please create a new question and add enough details like client and server setup and  preferable a packet capture (cloudshark.org).

Comment: I use Auto-signed certificate, and i don't check the validity of this certificate (client side), i think i must check this?? But can i check the validity of auto-signed certificate?
Does system run pretty the same with signed certificate?

Answer (score 0):

Yes if the cert is signed by a recognized CA (Certificate Authority), no if self-signed.

If you look in the Keychain under System Roots you will find over 200 CAs.